# What is the best practice to keep my Model separate from Entities in Doctrine2?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

OK, so now as I eventually decided to use Doctrine2 ORM in my new Zend2 project I have a question about the best design practices to maintain the Model and Entity classes separate. I'm *not* asking what's the difference between Entity and Model, I understand that. I also have my Service layer connected with Repository classes working just fine. What I'm asking, is a situation when I have a Model class with some business logic, let's say Document class, and then DocumentEntity which represents it's persistence, and just want to keep them separate, so for example, here is my Entity:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="DocumentRepo")
 * @ORM\Table(name="document")
 */
class DocumentEntity {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     * @ORM\Column(type="guid")
     */
    protected $guid;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(length=64)
     */
    protected $name;

    // more stuff below...
}
```

Now, there's my Model class with a lot of business logic that I want to keep separate:

```
class Document implements SomeImportantInterface, AnotherImportantInterface {

    public function doSomeImportantStuff() {
    }

    public function doEvenMoreImportantStuff() {
    }
}
```

And finally, the Service class:

```
class DocumentService  {
    const DOCUMENT_ENTITY = 'DocumentEntity';

    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    protected $em;

    /**
     * @param EntityManager $entityManager
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager) {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }


    public function getDocument($guid) {
        $documentEntity = $this->em->getRepository(self::DOCUMENT_ENTITY)->findByGuid($guid);

        return; //what? I want here Document to be returned, not the DocumentEntity..
    }

    public function createDocument() {
        return new Document();
    }

    public function saveDocument(Document $document) {
        // Document -> DocumentEntity

        // $documentEntity = ...?
        //$this->em->persist($entityDocument);
        //$this->em->flush();
    }
}
```

So as you can see, the plan is to have a Document objects that the application only cares about (accessible via Service), not the DocumentEntities. Two possible approaches that came to my mind:

- keep the DocumentEntity as a property inside the Document
- make Document to extend DocumentEntity

Or, maybe I'm just missing something in here, and just taking the wrong end of the stick? Looking forward to hear your opinions!

Answer (score 0):

Your entity should extend the model class.  Your application needs to do all it's model interaction via a repository interface.

```
DomainModel
    DocumentDomainModel
    DocumentDomainModelInterface
    DocumentDomainModelRepositoryInterface (get/create/save)

DoctrineEntity
    DocumentDoctrineEntity extends DocumentDomainModel
    DocumentDoctrineRepository implements DocumentDomainModelRepositoryInterface
```

This also gives you the flexibility to implement other repositories such as in memory one for testing.